# UIBezierPath contains: method does not detect touch on line thicker than 1 pixel

Tags: ios, swift

I draw a 10 point width path, but when I try to detect touches in it, UIBezierPath contains: method does only detect touches that happen at 1 pixel line and not 10 pixel line.

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: start)
    path.addLine(to: end)
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
    path.lineWidth = 10
    path.lineCapStyle = .round
    path.stroke()
    path.close()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = path.lineWidth
```

Here is a method to detect touch:

```
@objc func didTapOnView(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation:CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: self)
    self.hitTest(tapLocation: CGPoint(x: tapLocation.x.rounded(), y: tapLocation.y.rounded()))
}

private func hitTest(tapLocation: CGPoint){

    let path: UIBezierPath = path0

    print("Touch location is: \(tapLocation)")

    if path.contains(tapLocation){
       print("inside")
    } else{
        print("outside")
    }
}
```

I'm only getting touches that happen in exact 1 pixel line and not on 10 pixel line. If I don't do rounding, no touches get detected at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your path is only a line. For a line, `contains` only returns true for points that are on that line. It does not consider the stroke width. Of course, it is almost impossible to tap *exactly* on a line, which is why you don't detect any touches at all, unless you round the touch location.

You can get a `CGPath` representing the *stroked area* of a `UIBezierPath` using [`copy(strokingWithWidth:lineCap:lineJoin:miterLimit:transform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427133-copy). Then you can use `contains` to check whether a point is inside this area.

```
let path: UIBezierPath = path0.cgPath.copy(
    strokingWithWidth: 10,
    lineCap: .butt,
    lineJoin: .miter,
    miterLimit: 10
)

if path.contains(somePoint, using: .evenOdd) { ... }
```

Answer (score -3):

The Problem:

containsPoint: determines if a given point precisely is on the 1-pixel-wide line route in mathematics.
Due to restrictions on touch sensing and fingertip size, touches on a physical device are limited to a specific region rather than a single spot.

Resolutions:

Expand the Hit Area:

Make the unseen path bigger: Encircle your real line with an invisible UIBezierPath that has a slightly larger stroke. This unseen route serves as a touch detection hitbox.

```
let linePath = UIBezierPath()
// Draw your actual line here

// Create a wider invisible path for touch detection
let touchPath = UIBezierPath(rect: linePath.bounds.insetBy(x: -hitAreaWidth, y: -hitAreaWidth))

// Check touch events against the wider path
if touchPath.contains(touchPoint) {
    // Handle touch within the thicker line area
}
```

Customized Hit Test:

Create a unique hit test method that takes the touch position and line width into account:

```
func isTouchWithinLine(touchPoint: CGPoint, linePath: UIBezierPath, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> Bool {
// Calculate the line's bounding rectangle considering line width
let lineRect = linePath.bounds.insetBy(x: -lineWidth / 2, y: -lineWidth / 2)

// Check if the touch point is within the inflated rectangle with some tolerance 
let buffer: CGFloat = 5 // Adjust tolerance as needed
return lineRect.insetBy(x: -buffer, y: -buffer).contains(touchPoint)
```

}

Comment: Both of these suggestions assume that using the bounds of the path will do something useful, what if the line is a diagonal across the screen? You'll detect touches everywhere. copy stroking with width is the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).